# Deposit amount using Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Model.py

class Customers(models.Model):

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

contact = models.BigIntegerField(unique=True)

amount = models.BigIntegerField()

type = models.CharField(max_length=1)`
```

Form.py

class Deposit_Form(forms.Form):

```
amount = forms.IntegerField(min_value=200, label="Enter amount u want to deposit")
```

View.py

class Log_in(TemplateView):

```
template_name = 'login.html'

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    Form = Login()

    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': Form})

def post(self, request):

    username = self.request.POST.get('username').strip()

    password = self.request.POST.get('password').strip()

    if username is None or password is None:

        return HttpResponse({'Doesnt exist'}, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if not user:

        return HttpResponse({'Invalid candidate '}, status=HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    return redirect('customer_menu')
```

def customer_menu(request):

```
if "user_id" in request.session:

    return render(request, 'customer_menu.html')
```

class Deposit(TemplateView):

```
template_name = 'deposit.html'

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    Form = Deposit_Form()

    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': Form})

@staticmethod

def post(request):

    if "user_id" in request.session:

        data = request.POST.get

        try:

            deposit_amount=data('deposit_amount')

            customer = CustomerModel(

                amount = deposit_amount+amount
            )
            customer.save()

            return HttpResponse('action performed successfully', 500)

        except Exception as e:

            return HttpResponse("failed : {}".format(e), 200)
```

now i can't understand how can deposit amount, it show error in deposit class post function amount = deposit_amount + amount

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to increase your amount field on your Customer model. But firstly you must find your object which you want to update. And you can not directly `CustomerModel(amount=deposit_amount+amount)`.
 You can use `F()` function for this. For example: `CustomerModel.filter(pk=id).update(amount=F('amount')+deposite_amount)`

You can find detail  [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/expressions/) for detail about F() function

Edit:
As another way, you can find your CustomerModel object with `get()` method and increase your amount field. After, you can save your object.
Like that:

```
customer = CustomerModel.objects.get(pk=id) #you can change query field
customer.amount = customer.amount + data('deposite_amount')
customer.save()
```

Comment: what is CustomerModel.filter(pk=id)? is it user_id

Comment: No ı give only a sample. You must decide which object you want to update and based on this, you must find this object. You can use user_id field but, your model doesn't connected one to one with user. So you can access another CustomerModel mistakely. So, you must write your own filter logic.

Comment: it show this error 'DeferredAttribute' object has no attribute 'update'

Comment: def post(request):
        if "user_id" in request.session:

            data = request.POST.get

            try:
                deposit_amount = data('deposit_amount')

                customer = CustomerModel.amount.update(amount=F('amount') + deposit_amount)
                customer.save()
                return HttpResponse('action performed successfully', 500)
            except Exception as e:
                return HttpResponse("failed : {}".format(e), 200)

Comment: Okey, your  `CustomerModel.amount.update(amount=F('amount') + deposit_amount)` code is wrong. Because you must decide which db record you want to update? You must filtered firstly, after that you can update record. Like that `CustomerModel.objects.filter(you must fill here).update(amount=F('amount') + deposit_amount)`

Comment: customer = CustomerModel.objects.filter(user_id=request.session['user_id']).update(
                    amount=F('amount') + deposit_amount)
                customer.save()

Comment: failed : null value in column "amount" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (9, 3059088799, null, s, 108).

Comment: You don't need to save customer object again. update() method already save your filtered data. Also, based on [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/) The update() method is applied instantly and returns the number of rows matched by the query.

Answer (score 0):

What is the error?

make sure that this fields can be null

```py
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

contact = models.BigIntegerField(unique=True)

amount = models.BigIntegerField()

type = models.CharField(max_length=1)`
```